# VSTS Deploy Service Fabric Application task timeout on upgrade of deployed package

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using the Deploy Service Fabric Application task to automate the release of a service fabric application to a cluster.

The first issue we ran into was with the ReplicaQuorumTimeoutSec option in the PublishProfile. We kept getting this message in the Release logs:

```
ReplicaQuorumTimeoutSec is deprecated - use UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeoutSec
```

The release would be published to the cluster, but it wouldn't upgrade.

I removed the option and no longer got the above error, but the upgrade would still fail. Here are the logs:

```
Register application type succeeded
Start upgrading application...
##[debug]System.TimeoutException: Operation timed out. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BFF
##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricApplicationManagementClient8.EndUpgradeApplication(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClassa.<WrapNativeAsyncInvoke>b__9(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
##[debug]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
##[debug]System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ApplicationCmdletBase.<>c__DisplayClass19.<UpgradeApplication>b__17(Exception ae)
##[debug]   at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ApplicationCmdletBase.UpgradeApplication(ApplicationUpgradeDescription upgradeDescription)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.StartApplicationUpgrade.ProcessRecord()
Current Upgrade State: RollingForwardInProgress
Current Upgrade State: RollingForwardCompleted
Upgrade completed successfully.
```

Although the logs indicate that the update is successful, the update doesn't actually happen.

Finally, I tried changing the timeouts from 1 second to 120 seconds in the PublishProfile. This release fails completely with the following log lines:

```
Registering application type...
Register application type succeeded
Start upgrading application...
##[debug]System.Fabric.FabricException: aka.ms/upgrade-defaultservices ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BDF
##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeClient.IFabricApplicationManagementClient8.EndUpgradeApplication(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClassa.<WrapNativeAsyncInvoke>b__9(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
##[debug]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
##[debug]System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ApplicationCmdletBase.<>c__DisplayClass19.<UpgradeApplication>b__17(Exception ae)
##[debug]   at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ApplicationCmdletBase.UpgradeApplication(ApplicationUpgradeDescription upgradeDescription)
##[debug]   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.StartApplicationUpgrade.ProcessRecord()
Getting application health:


ApplicationName                 : fabric:/NetScribe.Hangfire.ServiceFabric.Dev
AggregatedHealthState           : Ok
ServiceHealthStates             : 
                                  ServiceName           : fabric:/NetScribe.Hangfire.ServiceFabric.Dev/HangFire
                                  AggregatedHealthState : Ok

DeployedApplicationHealthStates : 
                                  ApplicationName       : fabric:/NetScribe.Hangfire.ServiceFabric.Dev
                                  NodeName              : _nswjobs_0
                                  AggregatedHealthState : Ok

HealthEvents                    : 
                                  SourceId              : System.CM
                                  Property              : State
                                  HealthState           : Ok
                                  SequenceNumber        : 2852
                                  SentAt                : 8/28/2018 5:10:27 PM
                                  ReceivedAt            : 8/28/2018 5:10:27 PM
                                  TTL                   : Infinite
                                  Description           : Application health policy has been updated.
                                  RemoveWhenExpired     : False
                                  IsExpired             : False
                                  Transitions           : Warning->Ok = 8/28/2018 5:05:08 PM, LastError = 1/1/0001 
                                  12:00:00 AM


Failed to start application upgrade. Error aka.ms/upgrade-defaultservices.
Could not start upgrade successfully. Unregistering application type 'NetScribe.Hangfire.ServiceFabricType' and version '2.0.0.18249.06'.
Unregister application type started (query application types for status).
```

Here is the update portion of the PublishProfile:

```
<UpgradeDeployment Mode="UnmonitoredAuto" Enabled="true">
    <Parameters UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeoutSec="120" TimeoutSec="120" Force="True" ForceRestart="True"/>
</UpgradeDeployment>
```

Any help getting this working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, upgrade fails because of 2 reasons:

- a) If you change any of the data models in your stateful services [in reliable dictionaries] and your new data models are NOT compatible with the old version, [see wcf data contract versioning], upgrade will fail.
- b) If you did not honor the "cancellationtoken" in "Runasync" to exit, upgrade will timeout.

If not the  above 2 issues, most likely, the new code you introduced in your new version may be the problem. Make sure you create a local dev cluster with the production copy of your code and try to inject your new code with the upgrade and see what happens.